# Should gcc -fPIC option be used when compiling for x86_64 architectures?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, position-independent-code

The gcc documentation states, "This option makes a difference on AArch64, m68k, PowerPC and SPARC."  I don't see the x86 or x64 architectures listed.  AArch64 is related to ARM processors isn't it?  If compiling for the linux_x86_x64 then does this option produce any value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text you're quoting is from the GCC manual entry for `-fPIC` which directly follows [the entry for `-fpic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fpic).   **When they say "makes a difference", they mean *compared to `-fpic`*.**

> `-fpic`
> Generate position-independent code (PIC) suitable for use in a shared library, if supported for the target machine. Such code accesses all constant addresses through a global offset table (GOT). The dynamic loader resolves the GOT entries when the program starts (the dynamic loader is not part of GCC; it is part of the operating system). If the GOT size for the linked executable exceeds a machine-specific maximum size, you get an error message from the linker indicating that -fpic does not work; in that case, recompile with -fPIC instead. (These maximums are 8k on the SPARC, 28k on AArch64 and 32k on the m68k and RS/6000. The x86 has no such limit.)
>
> ...
>
> `-fPIC`
> If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size of the global offset table. This option makes a difference on AArch64, m68k, PowerPC and SPARC.
>
> ...

x86-64 can't save instructions or machine-code size with limited-range displacements because call/jump and RIP-relative addressing use `rel32` 32-bit displacements, so they can reach anywhere within +-2GiB of the instruction.  That's the full size allowed in the "small" and "small-PIC" code models, which is enough for basically anything, except sometimes huge arrays in `.bss`.  ("medium" and "large" use 64-bit absolute addresses for arrays over a certain threshold, or for everything which makes every function call an indirect jump).

x86-64 does have `jmp rel8` (but not `call rel8`), but compilers will only use that if one function happens to tailcall another in the *same* compilation unit, thus the instructions assemble into the same object file and the assembler can see the distance at assemble time and can choose a shorter branch encoding.  Jumps to code outside the current object file always get assembled to `jmp rel32`, because `jmp rel8` would rarely fit, only having -128..+127 byte range.  (And there's no way for the linker to make an instruction bigger if it needs more room; that would change the distance between instructions before and after it, which probably don't have relocation info since the assembler assumed distances were constant.)

---

**If you're compiling a shared library, yes you should use `-fPIC`.**  It's not different from `-fpic` on x86-64, but you need one or the other.

Although with modern distros configuring GCC with `-fPIE` as the default, the main difference on x86-64 is I think assuming symbol interposition is possible for global variables that aren't `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`.

`-fPIE` code-gen is suitable for shared libraries on x86-64 I think, but `-fno-pie` or `-fno-pic` isn't, and will give link errors when linking into a PIE or normal shared library.  (See *[32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)*)